# Creating unique ID only for new rows when they are added

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, uniqueidentifier, custom-function

I have a Google Sheet (with header row) and I need to create a uniqueID for each new row as it's added.

I can create the ID like this (an AppsScript)

```
function generate() { 
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
const row = sheet.getLastRow();
const randomUnique = `${Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)}-${Date.now()}`
}
```

and I call the function like this

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),,generate()))
```

Simply if there is a value in Column A create the ID

BUT when I add the final line to the generate() function I always get an error

This is the final line

```
 sheet.getRange(row,2 ).setValue(randomUnique);
```

This is the error

You do not have permission to call setValue()

To summarise, when row X column A has a value I need to have the ID created and inserted into row X Column B

Once set that ID must not change

How do I correct the function / formulas - thanks in advance

Comment: Is this meant to be used as a custom function ( in a cell)?

Comment: Hi @Cooper - I admit I may be doing this the wrong way, but I've used arrayformula on the column - in the example col B - so that it works (well it doesn't yet :) ) so that it affects every row even when a user adds new rows.  If it's I'm wrong then any suggestions to help correct greatly appreciated

Comment: See  [Should I include tags in title?](/help/tagging)

Comment: @Russell Parrott Thank you for replying. About `unless I'm doing something wrong I still get the same error.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, `setValues` cannot be used with the custom function. And I understood that you wanted to put the value as the fixed value. So, I proposed a method for achieving your goal without using the custom function. But, from your reply, it seems that you want to use the custom function. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike Requesting undeletion. You understood correctly and your answer is valid. OP just didn't understand how to use your solution.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your support. From OP's reply, I thought that I might have misunderstood OP's goal. So, I thought that my suggestion was not useful for OP's goal. But, from your comment, I understood it. By this, I reopened my answer. If this will be useful to OP and other users, I'm glad.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` a value.

```
function generate() { 
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    const activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
    //stop recalc, if needed:
    //if(activeRange.getValue() !== '') return activeRange.getValue();
    const activeRow = activeRange().getRow();
    const lrow = sheet.getLastRow();
    const randomUnique = () => `${Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)}-${Date.now()}`
    return randomUnique();
    //or return Array(lrow-activeRow).fill("").map(_ => [randomUnique()])
}
```

Comment: By just using return ALL rows update to the same "new" value.  Each row must be a unique value

Comment: @RussellParrott I would ask you to keep testing.  The way you're calling matters. If you use it inside a arrayformula, like you've shown in your question, it'll all the same id. Skip the arrayformula and drag fill or use `=byrow()` or return a array as shown in my answer. You need to practice repeatedly and spend more time testing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in the current stage, `setValue` cannot be used with the custom function. And also, when the values are put with the custom function, the values are changed by the recalculation. So, in this case, in order to achieve your goal of `To summarise, when row X column A has a value I need to have the ID created and inserted into row X Column B` and `Once set that ID must not change`, how about using a Google Apps Script as not the custom function? The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function mYFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + lastRow).getDisplayValues().map(([a, b]) => [a && b ? b : a && !b ? `${Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)}-${Date.now()}` : ""]);
  sheet.getRange("B2:B" + lastRow).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the columns "A" and "B" are checked. When there are the value of column "A" and no value of column "B", `${Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)}-${Date.now()}` is used. When there are the value of columne "A" and "B", the value of column "B" is not changed.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike - unless I'm doing something wrong I still get the same error.  Plus, as there are 4 worksheets that I'd like to run the function on is there a way to "remove"  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; and just use SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() ?

Comment: @Russell Parrott Thank you for replying. About `unless I'm doing something wrong I still get the same error.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, `setValues` cannot be used with the custom function. And I understood that you wanted to put the value as the fixed value. So, I proposed a method for achieving your goal without using the custom function. But, from your reply, it seems that you want to use the custom function. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.